# php dependencies

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to manage dependencies in php. I have seperated the php files into various folders. Sometimes they get interchanged between one another. The require_once statements change even if I used the absolute form. I was curious if anyone knows an easy way around this.

Answer (score 3):

Use relative paths in `require_once` and *stop moving the files between folders*

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to keep your includes all in one folder or the base directory. When you require_once a file inside of a file you yourself are requireing (like a chain), the path of the require in the later chain will eventually break if files are spread out. Instead, keep includes together and you should have no problem.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Also, if you have to have includes in different folders, make copies and keep those copies in folders. It is not the best strategy because files may need updates and i know i dont wanna copy and paste a file 10 times.